# Add a UIButton to an apps ViewController on iPhone/iPad with Theos

Tags: ios, objective-c, tweak, theos

Ok, I have an idea in mind for a MobileSubstrate tweak for an iPhone.

In this idea I wanted to add a button to the MobileSMS.app ViewController so the button would appear when the app is opened.

If anyone could help with the coding if this it would be much appreciated.

Also, if there is a way of doing it with Theos it would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

MobileSMS.app use Private Framework ChatKit.
so

for getting UIButton you have to create programmatically check the code below

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CKConversationListController : UIViewController
- (void)loadView;
@end

%hook CKConversationListController

- (void)loadView {
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    // now you can customize it for your own ;)
    [self.view addSubview:button]; // looks like CKConversationListController subclass of UIViewcontroller ;)
    %orig;
}

%end
```

then don't forget to link ChatKit in your MakeFile as XXX_PRIVATE_FRAMEWORKS = ChatKit

GoodLuck ;)